# PS script not run by Powershell Job

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use a powershell job to check if an app crashed recently and restart it if it crashed.
The script doing the checking and restarting the app works correctly when run separately. But, the job script is not executing it.

The check and restart script (CheckAndRestart.ps1):

```
$isProcessRunning = Get-Process "AppMain" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (!$isProcessRunning) {
    $events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='application';
                                 starttime=([datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-120));
                                 endtime=([datetime]::Now);
                                 } |Where-Object -Property Message -Like '*AppMain*'                           
    if ($events) {
        Start-Process -FilePath "shell:appsFolder\AppMain_9889wea!App"
    }
}
```

The script for creating the job:

```
$path = 'E:\Projects\AppMain\AppMainScript\CheckAndRestart.ps1'
$taskName = "AppMainScript"
$taskExists = Get-ScheduledJob | Where-Object {$_.Name -like $taskName }
if($taskExists) {
    Unregister-ScheduledJob -Name $taskName -Confirm:$false
}
$trigger_atlogon = New-JobTrigger -AtLogOn
$trigger_repetition = New-JobTrigger  -Once -At 11:40  -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1) -RepeatIndefinitely
Register-ScheduledJob -Name $taskName -Trigger @($trigger_atlogon,$trigger_repetition) -FilePath $path
```

Any ideas on why the job is not running the script?

**UPDATE**

I combined the two scripts into one. And the application appeared in the task manager, but the GUI of the application was not visible. Sometimes it would show the GUI, but most of the time id didn't.
I think there are some limitations or other details that I am not aware of.

Unfortunately I do not have time to investigate this situation further due to time constraints. I have created a WinForms app that does what the script should have.

Comment: are you sure that the script is NOT running? is it perhaps running but not doing anything? i would start by adding start/stop transcript commands and making sure that the account running the script has access to the location for the transcript.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey you were right with the assumption that the script worked. I described the behaviour I found in the update in my question. Thank your for the suggestions!

Comment: you are welcome! glad to help a tad ... and that you found a useful workaround! [*grin*]